# Biblatex: Brackets around the author in bibliography, author-year, DeclareFielFormat

Tags: biblatex

I just can't solve my problem. I want that in the Bibliography the authors are put in one [.........] bracket, like e.g. the dinat format does it. (Is not available since I am using Biblatex)

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 

\DeclareListFormat{author}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}     (*)
```

Thats my approach, but (*) does not cause any differences.

Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `biblatex` 3.12 onwards, you can use `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat` and `\DeclareListWrapperFormat` to formt the complete output of a  (name) list field (`\DeclareNameFormat` and `\DeclareListFormat` only format a single item). See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/754 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/829.

So if you want to print the author (or editor and translator in author position) in square brackets, you can simply use

```
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
```

In full

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde] (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

Since you mention `dinat` in your question, I suspect you actually want something slightly different. We can try and recreate the bibliography format of `dinat`, which introduces each entry with an author-year label, with [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear-icomp,
  bibstyle=ext-authortitle,
  sorting=nyt,
  introcite=plain,
  ]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias*[bbx@introcite]{nameyeardelim}[parencite]{nameyeardelim}
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998] Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

You can read more about `introcite` in [the `biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) (pp. 15-19).

If you prefer square brackets for `\parencite`/`\autocite`, have a look at `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims`.

---

The

```
\DeclareListFormat{author}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
```

had no effect, since `author` is a name list, whose format needs to be set up with `\DeclarNameFormat` (and `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat`). Declarations using the incorrect field type (`\DeclareListFormat{author}` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{author}`) are silently ignored.

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
```

would not have been ignored, but would not have produced the desired output, either, since name formats are quite special and don't work with the usual `#1`.

Comment: I had to make an update to the latest TeXLive, but this was nothing bad at all. Thank you for Your detailed answer! Fabulous! (This verifies that this very solution does work on the latest software)

Answer (score 1):

For old versions of biblatex (< v3.12, as for example used in overleaf) one can add the `\mkbibbrackets` to the author macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \mkbibbrackets{\printnames{author}}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}


\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With a current version of `biblatex` (at least v3.12, in particular the system run on Overleaf is much too old for that), the code block could simply be replaced with `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{author}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}`, though I would use `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}`, so that `editor`s and `translator`s in the same position are treated the same way.

Comment: @moewe I think it would be good if you would post this as an answer. I made clear that my one is for old systems

Comment: If you have a modern system and can verify that the code I suggested works I would be happy if you included it in your answer.

Comment: @moewe Unfortunately I currently don't have access to an up-to-date installation. I would be happy to see your answer

Comment: OK, in that case I will write an answer.