# Tweak authors in biblatex-gost

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I generate my bibliograhy with `biblatex` and `biblatex-gost`.
I need to tweak the display of authors in the bibliography:

1. The whole list of authors should start with `\by`
2. The initials should be placed *before* the surname
3. The initials should b separated with `\,`
4. There should be a `~` between initials and a surname

Thus, I need e.g.

```latex
\by C.\,J.~Goodwin, A.~Smith
```

Point 3 looks solved, but other do not.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cgood1980,
    Author = {Charles John Goodwin and Alice Smith},
    Journal = {Sociological Inquiry},
    Number = {3-4},
    Pages = {272-302},
    Title = {Restarts at turn-beginning},
    Volume = 50,
    Year = 1984,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}
    \parencite{cgood1980}
    
    \renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{\textbackslash,} % Works perfectly!

    % Desired result:
    % \by C.\,J.~Goodwin, A.~Smith

    %\renewcommand*{\bibinitperiod}{\~{\space}} % Does NOT what I need
    
    %\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % No effect!
    %\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last} % No effect!
    %\DeclareNameAlias{headingname:family-given}{last-first} % No effect!
    %\DeclareNameAlias{headingname:family-given}{first-last} % No effect!

    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I realize that (obviously!) it shouldn't be GOST-complaint; indeed, my goal is much more complex: I'm trying to create a workaround which should convert usual `biblatex` bibliography to `amsbib`-complaint one (`amsbib` is a dark Russian magic invented in Steklov Institute of Mathematics; like a guinea pig, it has nothing common neither with AMS nor with BibTeX). De-facto my solution is a wrapper over [`biblatex2bibitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex2bibitem), see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal/530638). The problem with authors seems to be the last known one that I have to solve; all the others are rather pathological.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `biblatex-gost` styles the names at the beginning of a bibliography entry are controlled by the `heading` name format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

% 1
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{heading}{\textbackslash by #1}
% 2
\DeclareNameAlias{heading}{given-family}
% 3
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{\textbackslash,}
% 4
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedelimd}{\textasciitilde}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cgood1980,
  Author  = {Charles John Goodwin and Alice Smith},
  Journal = {Sociological Inquiry},
  Number  = {3-4},
  Pages   = {272-302},
  Title   = {Restarts at turn-beginning},
  Volume  = 50,
  Year    = 1984,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \parencite{cgood1980}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: \by C.,J.~Goodwin, A.~Smith. Restarts at turn-beginning // Sociological Inquiry. — 1984. — Vol. 50, no. 3/4. — P. 272–302.]

Comment: Thank  you very much for the quick answer!  I encountered the only problem with p.1: I'm stuck to certain `biblatex` version because I sometimes post article to arXiv. Thus, I couldn't use `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat`. Instead of it, I (following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497926/biblatex-brackets-around-the-author-in-bibliography-author-year-declarefielfo)) concluded that `amsbib` never uses bibdashes, and I can redefine it: `\renewbibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}{\textbackslash by } \renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{}` (just for reference)